# Нужны ли тут кавычки?

Tags: пунктуация

Фраза такая: "Его особенно настораживают люди, которые, что называется, "себе на уме". Нужно ли в данном случае "себе на уме" брать в кавычки?

Answer (score 2):

Я бы не поставила кавычки. Вводное предложение "что называется" как бы указывает на то, что СЕБЕ НА УМЕ - устойчивое выражение. Кавычки выглядят лишними.

Answer (score 0):

Но здесь же есть фраза "что называется". Она позволяет брать названное выражение в кавычки.

Comment: Словарь Ушакова: Что называется (разг.) - употр. для указания на то, что именно это название, выражение здесь наиболее подходящее. Зима была, что называется, сиротская (т.е. теплая). Самый, что называется (прост.) - настоящий, самый подходящий; как раз, действительно.